# Run production server Java and node application in the background?

Tags: java, node.js, nginx, executable-jar

I have this complex web application where Nginx is running in the front to forward requests to a Node server and the Node server is using a Java .jar application. I want to run all these in a production environment. Nginx is no problem as it's running as a usual process. How do I run the Node application in the background so that it survives restarts and also the Java application (includes extra parameters to be set in both the application start command).

It's an Ubuntu Digitalocean machine. Here is the sample start commands-

sudo java -jar -Dapplication.secret=secret -Dapplication.publicurl=https://104.329.374.846:8888/ application.jar

sudo node server.js localhost:8888 secret

What will be the way to run both the applications in a way that when application will error out and stop (this is not a must) or Ubuntu will reboot, both these applications will auto restart on reboot, with the parameters in the commands auto set.

- List item

Comment: Follow [this](https://dzone.com/articles/run-your-java-application-as-a-service-on-ubuntu) for Jar and [this](https://hackernoon.com/making-node-js-service-always-alive-on-ubuntu-server-e20c9c0808e4) for node.js app.

Comment: @AnuragDwivedi I used this in the app.service file ExecStart but not working-

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/node /var/www/video.domain.com/openvidu-tutorials/openvidu-mvc-node/server.js localhost:4443 educake2019"

How can I make it work? There is no instruction on how to add these last parameters in the command. I used it like this but not working. What am I doing wrong? Tried with creating a bash script but deadend.

Answer (score 0):

For NodeJS app you have also [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) option which is easy to use.

Comment: Is there any pm2-like package for Java .jar applications?

Comment: @RPMcMurphy, I do not know any. I run my Java programs on server the same way that Anurang suggested above.